# Embed Custom Fullscreen Google Map into webpage

Tags: html, google-maps, architecture, maps, fullscreen

I want to know how to embed a fullscreen google map for a webpage (as background). I'd like this map to be custom with **no default controls** you'd use in the regular google maps online interface (only be able to scroll with mouse). Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

http://www.ijb.ca/contact/

Any insight would be great. I'm new to coding.

Comment: read up on the google maps api. You can easily remove the controls from the map. As far as making it a background. You create a div that contains the map and set the div to 100% height/width and `position:absolute` the content over the top

Comment: Consider using [MapBox](http://www.mapbox.com), its a really cool service for embedding custom maps

Comment: http://www.ijb.ca/contact/ is broken...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is very simple, i made an example here http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/T2F5Z/ and i also added the code bellow:

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="map"></div>

<div id="menu">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
    <h2>Header 2</h2>
    <h3>Header 3</h3>
    <h4>Header 4</h4>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
#map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;    
}

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var map;

    var style = [
        {
        stylers: [
            { saturation: "-100" },
            { lightness: "20" }
        ]
        },{
        featureType: "poi",
        stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
        ]
        },{
        featureType: "transit",
        stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
        ]
        },{
        featureType: "road",
        stylers: [
            { lightness: "50" },
            { visibility: "on" }
        ]
        },{
        featureType: "landscape",
        stylers: [
            { lightness: "50" }
        ]
        }
    ]

    var options = {
        zoom: 7,
        center:  new google.maps.LatLng(45.50867, -73.553992),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], options);
    map.setOptions({
        styles: style
    });

});
```

*Note: To remove the controls you need to use `disableDefaultUI: true`(see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI), to make the color black and white you need to set the map style, to make the map fullscreen you have to set the width and height 100%, and don't forget the absolute position like you see in the css.*

Comment: paulalexandru: I tried using the above example. I placed each piece in the correct areas, and nothing has occurred. My page is blank with no map....what did I do wrong? do I have to activate an API key somewhere (I tried to do that yesterday)...Sorry in advance for my naive coding questions...also I am using what appears to be HTML 5 through wordpress Patti theme.....thank you

Comment: latest: I did what you said, but my webpage shows up with nothing on it (completely white)....which is different than what showed up before....so maybe some sort of progress is being made...just to be clear what I've done: 1) inserted coding from each above category (HTML, CSS, JS) into respective locations in wordpress...I replaced everything in HTML with your newly replied link above. i'm currently hosting on a temp site.... visit: http://www.jasonrichardadams.com/ you can see what I mean with the "contact option 2" and "contact option 3"..nothing is showing up. thanks again for your help

Comment: will do. this has been very useful. i'm confused why the code would be messy. but i think i understand what you mean with the duplicate coding. i imputed everything from the **view source code** into my wordpress text editor...which is also in the separate boxes for CSS and JS in theme options

Comment: one confusing thing still is the inability for this to show up correctly in my wordpress site...even when i copy and paste everything from fiddle into a new fiddle window it doesn't work. it's got to be something with jquery because I'm entering everything correctly.

Comment: Remove <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> this jquery from your script because i see your wordpress already load jquery. I also sugest you ro install web developer addon for firefox because it will show you the errors on the page.

Comment: i see what you meant with that... here's my raw html for the page: <html>
<head>

    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&extension=.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
updatepage();
//--></script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <div id="menu">
        <h1>Header 1</h1>
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <h3>Header 3</h3>
        <h4>Header 4</h4>
    </div>
</body>
</html>.but when removing what you just said to do, my page only shows Header1 for content...sorry for the constant questions. this is frustrating as hell.

Answer (score 2):

It works, but of course you should add all scripts:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>     
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Customized Javascript Code for Map

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

            function init() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 11,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.578466,-73.840963),
                    scrollwheel: false, 
                    disableDefaultUI: true,

                    styles: [{stylers:[{hue:'#2c3e50'},{saturation:250}]},{featureType:'road',elementType:'geometry',stylers:[{lightness:50},{visibility:'simplified'}]},{featureType:'road',elementType:'labels',stylers:[{visibility:'off'}]}]
                };

                var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

                 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: map.getCenter(),
                            map: map,
                            title: 'Click to zoom'
                            });
            }
  </script>
```

Put it at the bottom of the page and then add a div to the HTML Body

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

And the css for the Div is

```
#map{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Now Create any div in your HTML Markup with any class name or Id name and give it a position where you want to place with some css and if you want to restyle your map use this tool . it is pretty useful

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html